# Dynamically changing template contents of a web form

Tags: user-interface, web

Let's say I want to build a web app which would use templates in the form similar to the following:

```
<h1>
  { status_text[step] }
</h1>
<progress max="10" value="{ value[step] }">
</progress>
```

In other words, let's say that I have lists `value[]` and `status_text[]`, change only the variable `step` over time and want the form to reflect these changes in the real-time (ideally, even without sending a notification from the code that changes `step`, so that I can use `current_time` instead of some artificial `step`). What technology should I use to implement such behaviour in the most elegant way? (for the main language, I'd prefer using Python but JS/PHP would also work if there's no Python-related solution)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kinds of task are always accomplished in the client side, In other words in **JavaScript**.

No matter you use **PHP** or **Python** for your backend logic, you need **JavaScript** to do that.

That said, if you want to use **pure JavaScript** or a library like **jQuery**, you will have to trigger an event on every change of the progress and update the value of the **h1** Element. I don't think this is the best solution for you.

So I suggest you using **AngularJs**. it's one of the leading web development technologies. **AngularJs** data binding allows you to accomplish this very easily. No need to trigger events or any extra work. if you're interested in AngularJs, here is a [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide) to get started.